# Converting TextView value to double variable

Tags: android

In front I set the text like that with the priceFormat being S$%.2f.

```
textPrice.setText(String.format(priceFormat, item.getPrice()));
```

Now I want to convert it to a double variable which I definitely think I have to make use of the priceFormat but I have no idea how to. This bottom line is wrong.

```
double Price=Double.parseDouble(textPrice.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the textPrice.getText() to a String since its Double.parseDouble(String):

```
double price = Double.parseDouble(mStatus.getText().toString());
```

You also have to eliminate the S$ and the trailing .:

```
double price = Double.parseDouble(mStatus.getText().toString().replaceAll("S\\$|\\.$", ""));
```

Of course you should make this less error-prone:

```
double price = 0d;
try {
    price = Double.parseDouble(mStatus.getText().toString().replaceAll("S\\$|\\.$", ""));
}
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // show an error message to the user
    textPrice.setError("Please enter a valid number");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to remove that `S$` before parsing, one of the way is:

```java
String text = textPrice.getText();
String priceText = text.split("$")[1].trim(); //splitting numeric characters with the currency characters
double priceVal = Double.parseDouble(priceText); //parsing it to double
```